# Twitter4j - quote tweet with full 280 characters for user text without url on quoted tweet

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I use `org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.6` for sanding tweets and `com.twitter:twitter-text:2.0.10` for tweet validation.

When I create quote tweet I put the link on the original tweet into the tweet text. Like this 
`Wow! This is cool! https://twitter.com/edent/status/554772317738659840`

And I expect all 280 characters available for my own text, but when I check tweet length after paste the quoted url it returns 23. For example tweet with text `https://twitter.com/edent/status/554772317738659840` returns `length = 23` and it means that only `257` (280-23) characters available for text. I check some other tweet clients on Android and they allow all 280 characters for text. How can I achieve this?

Code for update statuse: `twitter.updateStatus(new StatusUpdate("My tweet + quotedUrl"))`
Code for length check: `TwitterTextParser.parseTweet("My tweet  + quotedUrl").weightedLength`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer myself.
You dont need to add quoted tweet url in tweet body. You need to add it in `attachment_url` parameter, but `attachment_url` still doesn`t support in twitter4j (4.0.6 version) for some reason.

You can add sources of twitter4j-core in your project and added it parameter yourself.

More info about `attachment_url` parameter:  https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates